# Re-captcha token getting from blockchain

Tags: graphql, jmeter

How to extract  re-captcha token from blockchain in jmeter

I want a token id from blockchain and implement in another graphql Request as variable

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about JSON response, you can use Json Exractor (post processor). If you have some sort of mechanism to access it. Usually the idea ot re-captcha is to prevent automation :)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can, as per definition [CAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) stands for

> Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart

the whole idea behind it is to prevent automation. Theoretically it is possible to bypass CAPTCHA by using [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) but you will have to heavily invest into [computer vision](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d52/tutorial_java_dev_intro.html) and [machine learning](https://www.baeldung.com/java-ai) and your test will use **a lot** of resources.

Also there are [Captcha solving services](https://geekflare.com/captcha-solving-services-api/) providing APIs if you don't have the time to implement it yourself but you have enough money to pay for the solution.

However CAPTCHA in general and [reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/) in particular should be completely out of your testing scope so ask your application developers or administrators to turn it off for your test environment for your test duration.